# Одно нажатие вместо двух разных

Tags: java, android, android-on-click

Был одна кнопка, работало всё замечательно, решил добавить вторую и понеслось, хотя в ней метод и другой но делает она то же самое что и первая, а первая в свою очередь не работает. Возможно дело в обработчиках нажатия, но если честно на мой ещё совсем не профессианальный взнгляд вроде всё норм.

```
this.infoButtonListener = new OnInfoWindowElemTouchListener(callButton,
            getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.round_but_green_sel),
            getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.round_but_red_sel))
    {
        @Override
        protected void onClickConfirmed(View v, Marker marker) {
            makeCall(marker);
        }
    };
    this.callButton.setOnTouchListener(infoButtonListener);


    this.infoButtonListener = new OnInfoWindowElemTouchListener(sendButton,
            getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.round_but_red_sel),
            getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.round_but_red_sel))
    {
        @Override
        protected void onClickConfirmed(View v, Marker marker) {
            sendEmail();
        }
    };
    this.sendButton.setOnTouchListener(infoButtonListener);
```

Подскажите пожалуйста как исправить проблему?

Вариант решения

```
nInfoWindowElemTouchListener listenerCall = new OnInfoWindowElemTouchListener(sendButton,
            getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.round_but_green_sel),
            getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.round_but_red_sel)) {

        @Override
        protected void onClickConfirmed(View v, Marker marker) {
            sendEmail();
        }
    };
    this.sendButton.setOnTouchListener(infoButtonListener);
```

Comment: Попробуйте не переназначать полю класса новый экземпляр класса, (ибо зачем?), а, вместо этого, создавать новую переменную `OnInfoWindowElemTouchListener listenerCall = new OnInfoWindowElemTouchListener(){} `

Comment: @ЮрийСПб Вариант решения добавил, примерно так? или опять что то не то?

Comment: Типа того. Только имя переменной не удачное. Ну и назначить потом слушатель вьюхе надо

Comment: @ЮрийСПб обновил, но по прежнему listenerCall нигде не используется.

Comment: Используйте его вместо infoButtonListener

Comment: @ЮрийСПб Спасибо, всё получилось) Можно идти на боковую, только проголосавать за Ваши ответы хотелось бы) реально помогли)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас какая-то путаница в ссылках на слушатель тача приключилась. В данном случае можно слушатели нажатий назначать создав отдельную переменную для каждой

```
OnInfoWindowElemTouchListener listenerCall = new OnInfoWindowElemTouchListener(sendButton,
        getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.round_but_green_sel),
        getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.round_but_red_sel)) {

    @Override
    protected void onClickConfirmed(View v, Marker marker) {
        sendEmail();
    }
};
this.sendButton.setOnTouchListener(listenerCall);
```

или даже просто передавая анонимный класс, не создавая лишних переменных так:

```
this.sendButton.setOnTouchListener(new OnInfoWindowElemTouchListener(sendButton,
        getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.round_but_green_sel),
        getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.round_but_red_sel)) {

    @Override
    protected void onClickConfirmed(View v, Marker marker) {
        sendEmail();
    }
});
```